# How to make divs align like a table

Tags: html, css

With the following code I'd like for each div to display to the right of the previous span, like in the second td of a tr in a table, and each subsequent div to display below the previous div.  I've tried float: right and div div:first in various configurations and everything has so far looked completely different from what I need.  I'd love to know what I'm missing.  If anyone can assist I'd really appreciate it!

```
<div>
    <span>Left side of all inner divs</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Left side of first row</span>
            <div>
                <span>Right</span>
                <span>side</span>
                <span>of first</span>
                <span>row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Left side of second row</span>
            <div>
                <span>Right side</span>
                <span>of second row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>Whole</span>
                <span>third</span>
                <span>row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Whole fourth row</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something with flex or grid display.

Something like this :

```css
.Table-Container {
    display: flex;
}

.Table-Aside {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width : 200px;
    background : #f4f4f4;
    border : solid 1px #1c1c1c;
}

.Table {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: rows;
    width: 100%;
}

.Table__Row {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;

    /* Repeat cell of same size with min-width 50px, and max = available width */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr)); 
}

.Table__Cell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border : solid 1px #1c1c1c;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Table-Container">
    <div class="Table-Aside">
        <span>Left side of all inner divs</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Table">
        <div class="Table__Row">
            <div class="Table__Cell">
                <span>Left side of first row</span>
            </div>
            <div class="Table__Cell">
                <span>Right</span>
                <span>side</span>
                <span>of first</span>
                <span>row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Table__Row">
            <div class="Table__Cell">
                <span>Left side of second row</span>
            </div>
            <div class="Table__Cell">
                <span>Right side</span>
                <span>of second row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Table__Row">
            <div class="Table__Cell">
                <span>Whole</span>
                <span>third</span>
                <span>row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Table__Row">
            <div class="Table__Cell">
                <span>Whole fourth row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to work really well!  It's nice to be introduced to flexbox and grid.  I'll need to learn a lot more about them.

Comment: Perfect, feel free to mark this proposition as an accepted answer. Good luck in your learning process !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="table">
    <span>Left side of all inner divs</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Left side of first row</span>
            <div>
                <span>Right</span>
                <span>side</span>
                <span>of first</span>
                <span>row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Left side of second row</span>
            <div>
                <span>Right side</span>
                <span>of second row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>Whole</span>
                <span>third</span>
                <span>row</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Whole fourth row</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.table {
  display: flex;
}

div.table > div > div {
  display: flex;
}
```

Is it right?

Comment: It didn't work but thank you for suggesting flex boxes!  I'm looking into how to use them.  Thanks!